# SQL ORDER BY multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to sort my products table by two columns: `prod_price` and `prod_name`.

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_price, prod_name
FROM Products
ORDER BY prod_price, prod_name;
```

How is the sorting done here?  I think it happens first by `prod_price` and then by `prod_name`. Also, how is the above query different from this one:

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_price, prod_name
FROM Products
ORDER BY prod_name;
```

My products table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
  prod_id    char(10)      NOT NULL ,
  vend_id    char(10)      NOT NULL ,
  prod_name  char(255)     NOT NULL ,
  prod_price decimal(8,2)  NOT NULL ,
  prod_desc  text          NULL 
);
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sorting in an `ORDER BY` is done by the first column, and then by each additional column in the specified statement.

For instance, consider the following data:

```
Column1    Column2
=======    =======
1          Smith
2          Jones
1          Anderson
3          Andrews
```

The query

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM thedata ORDER BY Column1, Column2
```

would first sort by all of the values in `Column1`

and then sort the columns by `Column2` to produce this:

```
Column1    Column2
=======    =======
1          Anderson
1          Smith
2          Jones
3          Andrews
```

In other words, the data is first sorted in `Column1` order, and then each subset (`Column1` rows that have `1` as their value) are sorted in order of the second column.

The difference between the two statements you posted is that the rows in the first one would be sorted first by `prod_price` (price order, from lowest to highest), and then by order of name (meaning that if two items have the same price, the one with the lower alpha value for name would be listed first), while the second would sort in name order only (meaning that prices would appear in order based on the `prod_name` without regard for price).

Comment: And just for fun (but not only for fun): there is another way to sort data in DBMS which supports window syntax: `select *, count(*) over (order by Column1, Column2) from thedata`

Answer (score 8):

The results are ordered by the first column, then the second, and so on for as many columns as the ORDER BY clause includes. If you want any results sorted in descending order, your ORDER BY clause must use the DESC keyword directly after the name or the number of the relevant column.

Check out this Example

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date, salary 
FROM employee 
ORDER BY hire_date DESC,last_name ASC;
```

It will order in succession. Order the Hire_Date first, then LAST_NAME it by Hire_Date .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sorting is different.

Items in the `ORDER BY` list are applied in order.
Later items only order peers left from the preceding step.

Why don't you just *try*?

Comment: I think sorting by prod_name only gets done when prod_price columns have same values otherwise it gets sorted by prod_name . Please tell if i am correct

Comment: @user2201462: That's what the word *peer* means. Those rows are all the same in regard to a certain `ORDER BY` item. Only those are subject to the next item.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of your database.

SQL is based on the SET theory: there is no order inherently used when querying a table.

So if you were to run the first query, it would first order by product price and then product name, IF there were any duplicates in the price category, say $20 for example, it would then order those duplicates by their names, therefore always maintaining that when you run your query it will always return the same set of result in the same order.

If you were to run the second query, it would only order by the name, so if there were two products with the same name (for some odd reason) then they wouldn't have a guaranteed order after you run the query.

Answer (score 1):

yes,the  sorting  proceed differently. 
in first scenario, orders based on column1  and  in addition to that process further by sorting colmun2 based on column1 ..
in second scenario  ,it orders completely based on column 1 only...
please  proceed  with a  simple example...u  will get  quickly..